# Cannot resolve module while trying to organize modules in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, es6-modules

I'm new to React Native and am trying to organize my React Native classes into modules to get rid of the "`import from '../../../`" mess. Here's my very simple folder structure:

[image]

Following the tutorial at [here](https://medium.com/skyshidigital/5-best-practices-for-react-native-development-you-probably-doesnt-know-474df87d74e6), I've structured my `package.json` as this for each folder:

```
{
    "name": "@foldername"
}
```

Now, I'm trying to import `Page` (which is just a component superclass at this time, exported as default in the file):

`import Page from '@app/components/core';`

But it cannot be resolved. I've also tried:

`import Page from '@app/@components/@core';`

`import { Page } from '@app/@components/@core';`

`import { Page } from '@app/components/core';`

`import { Page } from 'app/components/core';`

None of them seem to be working. I've also tried them all without the `@` sign (removing it from both the package files and import statement), but no avail.

How can I organize my components to work that way (and it would be great if I knew what that `@` sign in front does, as I've also seen some tutorials without it)?

Here is my `package.json` in my root folder if it helps (haven't touched it, it's the way created by `react-native init`):

```
{
  "name": "redacted",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.2",
    "babel-jest": "^24.5.0",
    "jest": "^24.5.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.53.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: @CraftyMonkey you mean the app's default one at root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my bad.

Instead of using it like:

`import MyComponent from 'package/path/MyComponent'`

I was using:

`import MyComponent from 'package/path'` (without my class file at the end).

I've imported it correctly (also removed the `app` package and the `@` prefixes and directly referenced `components` as a package in its `package.json` file) (including the component name):

`import Page from 'components/core/Page';`

It worked perfectly.

Comment: Tbf, we all should've spotted that!

Answer (score 5):

add `babel-plugin-module-resolver` to devDependencies.
If you have `.babelrc` just delete it and add `babel.config.js`. And add aliases there. It should look like this

```
function babelConfig(api) {
  if (api) {
    api.cache(false);
  }

  const presets = ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'];
  const plugins = [
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        alias: {
          appColors: './src/Colors',
          appConstants: './src/Constants',
          components: './src/Components',
          screens: './src/Screens',
          utils: './src/utils'
        },
        cwd: 'babelrc'
      }
    ]
  ];

  return {
    presets,
    plugins
  };
}

module.exports = babelConfig;
```

Then you can use import like this

```
import { YourComonent } from 'components';
```

make sure you have exported as default.
Also, don't try to set the alias names with capital letters

This works with the latest react-native (0.59.3).

Here is my devDependencies

```
devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.4.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.4.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "0.0.3",
    "babel-eslint": "8.2.2",
    "babel-jest": "24.5.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.2.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.9.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.10.0",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.5",
    "eslint": "5.15.3",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "16.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.9.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "3.2.1",
    "jest": "24.5.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.53.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using VSCode, Intellisense of the IDE does not recognise just the package.json; include a tsconfig/jsconfig JSON file (TypeScript [ftw]/ JavaScript)

In `compilerOptions` add :

```
"paths" : {
    "@alias1*" : ["./alias1/*"],
     .....
  }
```

For all your aliases. Then the editor should pick up your files.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig

If you choose not to use VSCode, use Babel:

If your project doesn’t use Webpack - for example if you’re working with React Native, you can use your .babelrc file and a babel plugin to get aliasing set up.

Firstly, you’ll want to install babel-plugin-module-resolver with yarn or npm.

Once you’ve done that, open up your project’s .babelrc file, and under the plugins key, add this:

```
[
  'module-resolver',
  {
    root: ['./src'],
    alias: {
      myAlias: './src',
    },
  },
];
```

Or use the package.json in root

Comment: I am using VSCode but if I do this will it be able to compile correctly without VSCode, since there might be other collaborators in the future?

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu - if you use VSCode, you'll need the jsconfig, if not the normal package.json should work. If you don't want to commit it in your project, include it in your .gitignore. Has the suggested worked for you? I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

In `tsconfig.json`, add the following :

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "app"
...
}
```